# Processing Huge CSV File using Producer - Consumer Pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, producer-consumer, opencsv

I am trying to process an arbitary CSV File which can range from 10 records to million records. The CSV File has 4 fixed columns (e.g. a,b,c,d) and 2 additional columns (e,f) which come from external REST API.

My goal is to read all the records from CSV and for each record, call the external REST API to bring 2 additional columns and output the resultant CSV as merged CSV. The output should be same csv file with columns (a,b,c,d,e,f).

I implemented this scenario using **Content Enricher pattern** from EIP using Spring Integration and was able to achieve the expected output, however this solution works well for low number of records as I read the CSV file sequentially, but as soon as the no. of records increases, the time to execute the program increases too in *O(n)* fashion.

I further started implementing Producer - Consumer design pattern and tried to implement the code in such a way that Each record read from CSV is then put into a Queue using *put()* and then multiple Consumers read from the same shared Queue using *take()* method of BlockingQueue. The Main program instantiates ExecutorService with 1 Producer and multiple consumers by using **Executors.newFixedSizedThreadPool(3)**, however I am facing couple challenges:

1. The take() method never exits out. I tried implementing Poison Pill by adding a terminator object and then checking for the same poison pill in Consumer loop to break out, but it still never breaks out (I added a system out in the loop to see if it ever reaches Poison Pill and it does print my statement out), so why does it not exit out?
2. The CSV file only keeps the data read from the last executed Consumer thread and overwrites everything writing from other consumers- I am using OpenCSV to read / write CSV Data.

Here is the code I have uptil now. Can someone please guide me where I am wrong and areas to improve in this code?

**Main Program**

**

```
BlockingQueue<Account> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
    AccountProducer readingThread = new AccountProducer(inputFileName, queue);
    //new Thread(readingThread).start();
    ExecutorService producerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    producerExecutor.submit(readingThread);

    AccountConsumer normalizers = new AccountConsumer(outputFileName, queue, accountService );
    ExecutorService consumerExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        consumerExecutor.submit(normalizers);
    }
    producerExecutor.shutdown();
    consumerExecutor.shutdown();
```

**AccountProducer**

```
public class AccountProducer implements Runnable {
private String inputFileName;
private BlockingQueue<Account> blockingQueue;
private static final String TERMINATOR = "TERMINATOR";

public AccountProducer (String inputFileName, BlockingQueue<Account> blockingQueue) {

    this.inputFileName = inputFileName;
    this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
}


@Override
public void run() {

    try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(inputFileName));) {

        PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(java.util.Date.class, DateEditor.class);
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Account> strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<>();
        strategy.setType(Account.class);
        String[] memberFieldsToBindTo = { "accountId", "accountName", "firstName", "createdOn" };
        strategy.setColumnMapping(memberFieldsToBindTo);

        CsvToBean<Account> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Account>(reader).withMappingStrategy(strategy)
                .withSkipLines(1).withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true).build();

        Iterator<Account> csvAccountIterator = csvToBean.iterator();

        while (csvAccountIterator.hasNext()) {
            Account account = csvAccountIterator.next();    
            // Checking if the Account Id in the csv is blank / null - If so, we skip the
            // row for processing and hence avoiding API call..
            if (null == account.getAccountId() || account.getAccountId().isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                // This call will send the extracted Account Object down the Enricher to get
                // additional details from API
                blockingQueue.put(account);
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Account account = new Account();
                account.setAccountId(TERMINATOR);
                blockingQueue.put(account);
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**AccountConsumer**

```
public class AccountConsumer implements Runnable {

private String outputFileLocation;
private BlockingQueue<Account> blockingQueue;
private AccountService accountService;

public AccountConsumer(String outputFileLocation, BlockingQueue<Account> blockingQueue, AccountService accountService) {
    this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
    this.outputFileLocation = outputFileLocation;
    this.accountService = accountService;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        while (true) {
            Account account = blockingQueue.poll();
            account = accountService.populateAccount(account);
            accounts.add(account);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    processOutput(accounts, outputFileLocation);
}

/**
 * The method processOutput simply takes the list of Accounts and writes them to
 * CSV.
 * 
 * @param outputFileName
 * @param accounts
 * @throws Exception
 */
private void processOutput(List<Account> accounts, String outputFileName) {

    System.out.println("List Size is : " + accounts.size());
    // Using try with Resources block to make sure resources are released properly
    try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(outputFileName, true);) {
        StatefulBeanToCsv<Account> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
        beanToCsv.write(accounts);
    } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        //logger.error("Unable to write the output CSV File : " + ex);
        //throw ex;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Spring Integration XML I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task">

<channel id="accountChannel" /> 
<!-- accountOutputChannel is used for putting the Account object on the 
Channel which will then be consumed by accountAPIChannel as Input to the API 
-->
<channel id="accountOutputChannel" />
<!-- accountAPIChannel will take 1 accountId at a time and invoke REST API 
Service to get additional details required to fill the Content Enricher -->
<channel id="accountAPIChannel" />

<!-- accountGateway is the entry point to the utility -->
<gateway id="accountGateway" default-request-timeout="5000"
    default-reply-timeout="5000"
    service-interface="com.epe.service.AccountService"
    default-request-channel="accountChannel">
</gateway>

<!--Content  enricher is used here for enriching an existing message with 
additional data from External API
     This is based on EIP Pattern - Content Enricher -->
<enricher id="enricher" input-channel="accountOutputChannel"
    request-channel="accountAPIChannel">
    <property name="status" expression="payload.status" />
    <property name="statusSetOn" expression="payload.createdOn" />
</enricher>
```

```
<beans:bean id="accountService"
    class="com.epe.service.impl.AccountServiceImpl" />

<!-- Below service-activator is used to actually invoke the external REST 
API which will provide the additional fields for enrichment -->
<service-activator id="fetchAdditionalAccountInfoServiceActivator"
    ref="accountInfoService" method="getAdditionalAccountInfoService" 
input-channel="accountAPIChannel"
    />

<!-- accountInfoService is a bean which will be used for fetching 
additional information from REST API Service -->
<beans:bean id="accountInfoService"
    class="com.epe.service.impl.AccountInfoServiceImpl" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I think you need redesign the way you handled InterruptException in both producer and consumer

Comment: Can you show me an example w.r.t my code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `poll()` in the code, not `take()`.

You should use `poll()` with a timeout instead e.g. `poll(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` so you can terminate each thread gracefully.

But, you don't need all this logic; you can achieve all of this using Spring integration components - `ExecutorChannel` and file outbound channel adapter in append mode.

**EDIT**

I don't have time to write your entire application, but essentially you need...

```xml
<file:inbound-channel-adapter />
<file:splitter output-channel="execChannel"/>
<int:channel id="execChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="exec" />
</int:channel>
<int:transformer /> <!-- OpenCSV -->
<int:enricher ... />
<int:transformer /> <!-- OpenCSV -->
<int:resequencer /> <!== restore order -->
<file:outbound-channel-adapter />
```

You can read about all these components in the reference manual.

You also might want to consider using the Java DSL instead of xml; something like...

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(File.inboundChannelAdapter(...))
              .split(Files.splitter())
              .channel(MessageChannels.executor(exec())
              .transform(...)
              .enrich(...)
              .transform(...)
              .resequence()
              .handle(File.outboundCHannelAdapter(...))
              .get();
```

Comment: Thanks Gary - Can you show an example of what you suggested? I am still new to Spring Integration.

Comment: `FileSplitter->executorChannel->openCSV->enricher->openCSV->fileOutboundAdapter`. You would need to add a `resequencer` if you want to retain record order. You need to show your current Spring Integration configuration if you need me to be more specific.

Comment: Adding the XML to the Original post. I have also added comments on each component in the XML so you can understand what I am doing on Java side and Spring XML side.. Let me know if I need to provide anything else?

Comment: Thanks Gary - Your idea of using poll with time unit worked for me. That was the only part missing. I am able to exit it gracefully now. My Second issue of data being overwritten was solved by introducing another Queue which solely does the work of writing the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

In AccountProducer

```
catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex);
 }
```

This is not proper way to handle InterruptedException. The ExecutorService uses interruption for forced shutdown (shutDownNow()), but since you eat the interruption the ExecutorService will not be responsive to forced shotdown.

In AccountConsumer

```
catch (InterruptedException e) {
 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

This ensures that the Thread will reraise the InterruptedException which can be redesign as

```
try {
        while (true) {
            Account account = blockingQueue.poll();
            account = accountService.populateAccount(account);
            accounts.add(account);
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted and hence exiting...");
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

**EDIT**
Also ExecutorService call to shutdown() doesn’t cause an immediate destruction

One good way to shut down the ExecutorService with the awaitTermination() method